# How do I make this section background responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, responsive

I'm trying to make the background on my `<section>` tag responsive, for some reason it won't adapt when I change my browser size. Am I having conflicting codes?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');
@keyframes breath {
  0% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 140% auto;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
}

#bkg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: breath 100s linear infinite;
}

section {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: ;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-image: url(img/bg.png); background-size: cover;"></section>
```

Comment: Remove the `.` in `.section` in your CSS, you need to reference the element not a CSS class called `section`

Comment: @Lawless Already removed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

section tag don't get impacted with `.section` this one reference tag with `class="section"` not `<section>` check revised code below :

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/24/18/05/background-3104413_960_720.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>Lorem Ipsum</section>
```

Comment: got your point but I still get the same result, the image wont resize when I change my browser size

Comment: I got it here : https://jsfiddle.net/xaqL9wos/, i didn't understand what do you mean by *image wont resize*

Comment: Do you mean responsive image. If so look here how to create an responsive image with CSS : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp